# Spring Repository PreAuthorize gives 'failed to evaluate expression' error

Tags: spring, spring-security

i'm adding lots of bold because someone downgraded my question which is think is strange...

**i went from this which worked which means things are configured correctly for @PreAuthorize...**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping('/people')
public PersonController extends BaseController {
   @PreAuthorize("#pesonId != principal.id")
   @RequestMapping(value="updatePerson", method={RequestMethod.POST}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public @ResponseBody SimpleResponseStatus updatePerson(@RequestParam(personId) final Long personId, @RequestParam(value) final String value, final HttpServerRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
   {
      Person p = personRepo.findById(personId);
      p.setValue(value);
      personRepo.save(p);
   }
}
```

**and moved to this which doesn't work** ... the @PreAuthorize in the Repository save()...

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("#p.id != principal.id")
  Person save(person p);

}
```

and now i get a "Failed to evaluate expression '#p.id != principal.id'

One difference between when it was working on the Controller was i did #personId and not #p.id so i don't know if the object vs primitive in the expression is the problem or if Controller vs Repository (where i do the evaluation) is the problem.

So i have a few questions...

1. Do i have to do anything special to get the PreAuthorize working in the Repository?
2. Nothing to do with Spring security but why was i forced to add the SuppressWarnings?    i can see if i was returning `List<Person>` maybe but i thought that was strange.
3. There is another instance where i will want to do an a PreAuthorize expression like "#p.group.id != 3" ... is there a limit to the levels that can be in an evaluation?    i.e. level = obj.obj.obj.obj.value

Another interesting thing is that when i had it working with the Controller i didn't need curly braces "#{userId != 3}" but it worked with "#userId != 3" and i got that syntax from [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-security/preauthorize-postauthorize-in-spring-security).

**Bottom line, i had it working in a Controller but without an object parameter and now i need it to work in a Repository and with an object parameter.  And i've tried #person.id != 3 as well as #{person.id != 3} and neither work.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the answer to my own question:  [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2376)

which is basically for the Repository you have to add a parameter name via annotation since the debug isn't compiled into the interface.

it took me a long time to finally find the answer as it took trial and error of me trying different EL syntax and finally one syntax i chose gave me a different (and better) error message and from there i found the link above.

Anyway, whoever downgraded my question should have just posted the link i just did above instead of downgrading me.  that is just mean, really.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  @PreAuthorize("#p.id != principal.id")
  Person save(@Param("p") person p);  //the @Param annotation is needed!

}
```

also, it is interesting how some places i see {} are needed and other places not.  i did not need braces for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

you must first:
- enable global method security

in your spring security config just add

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
```

the you can safely use @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize

- correct SPEL syntax should be

  #{pesonId != principal.id}

but...before this you should ensure both parameter are present in SPringEvaluationContext.

I suggest to use Spring approach, which doesn't fit you question but gives you a different point of view of the problem.

Usage of expression bases access control
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

ex: `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`

Spring security accept any valid Spel inside annotation.
Take a look here:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic

Comment: thanks for the reply.  as i mentioned i had it working already on the Controller and just tried to move it to the Repository interface.  so i already had EnableGlobalMethodSecurity set up.  in my Controller that worked i didn't have curly braces but i have seen documentation that shows curly braces.  my main problem now is that  #person.id != 3 and #{person.id != 3} both don't work.

Comment: Reason is they are not part of springevaluationcontext, take a look to the second li k